# Fetch All Properties Missing Room Information

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

this is a question and possibly an improvement request.  When I use the model derivative api to fetch object properties from a converted Revit model, I don't understand why it won't fetch the room data.

In my example we are only processing 2D views, and those 2D views are interactive, similar to BIM 360 I'm able to select a room and query its properties in forge viewer.  So I know the properties are there in the conversion, but for some reason, Object Tree doesn't give room objects and thus it doesn't give room parameter data.

**What I tried:**

1. Convert a Model Revit Model floor plan using the model derivative API.  Viewing the model in Forge Viewer should allow you to select a room element and query its properties, such as the screenshot below.

[Image of Room Selected in Forge Viewer Floor Plan View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLiw4.png)

so we know the data for the Room objects is in the forge conversion.

2. Using the model derivative api to fetch the object tree and / or metadata, the room objects don't exist.  I read something that seemed to indicate to generate master views, but I'm not sure I understand why that is necessary because the 2D conversions I am doing, we aren't generating master views, but still seem to have the room data accessible in Forge Viewer.

**What I expected**
It seems to me as a developer and user that the model derivative API could fetch the room objects and their data.  Please correct me if I'm missing something.

Comment: Hi @joshmoore2911, I'm sorry to hear this issue is bothering you. I'm checking with our engineering team, but to ensure we're in the same boat, is your 2D view a floor plan view or a sheet view? and are all rooms missing from the object tree or just some of them?

Comment: Could you test with [rac_basic_sample_project.rvt,](https://www.autodesk.com/revit-rac-basic-sample-project-2022-enu) and check if the 2d view `102 - Plans` reproduce the issue you addressed?

Comment: BTW, the master view is used to generate Room 3D geometries, not room info.

Comment: I haven't been lucky to hear back from you, but what is your Revit model version? If it's equal to or higher than Revit 2022, it would be related to a known issue, DERI-9295.

Comment: Hi @EasonKang thanks for the message.  These are floor plan views, not sheet views and best I can tell, all of the room objects seem to be missing from the object tree.  I'm wondering if this has to do with design options.  In our use case, the room objects are in design options in each of the views we are processing.

Comment: Also, thanks for clarifying about the generate master views.  Also, this was with Revit 2022.  Where would I find the information on the known issue you posted, DERI-9295? I'm not sure where to look to find it.

Comment: Hi @EasonKang I did another test on a different model and I am seeing the room objects, both for rooms in design options and the main model.  I'm not sure why the other model I tried didn't have it, but right now it seems to work, I appreciate you responding on this!

Comment: if the model was with Revit 2022, then could you try to rename the file with another name, upload it to the OSS bucket, and request a translation with this advanced option (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFNcz.png) and request the object tree?